# Print an image multiple times on the same sheet c#

Tags: c#, printing, barcode

Hi I would like to print a product barcode in a sheet but if the user write 6 products on stock it must print 6 times this code on the sheet, I have a code but it prints just one code per image, please see it below.

```
private void generar_codigo_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string codigo_generado = nom_prd_txt.Text; 
        BarcodeLib.Barcode Codigo = new BarcodeLib.Barcode();
        Codigo.IncludeLabel = true;
        codigo_pic.BackgroundImage = Codigo.Encode(BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE128, codigo_generado, Color.Black, Color.White, 173, 102);

        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
        doc.PrintPage += Doc_PrintPage;
        pd.Document = doc;
        if (pd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            doc.Print();
    }

    private void Doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(codigo_pic.Width, codigo_pic.Height);
        codigo_pic.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(5, 5, codigo_pic.Width, codigo_pic.Height));
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0);
        bm.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Is there something stopping you from drawing the image 6 times in the `Doc_PrintPage` method where you are already drawing it? Why not just lay it out however you need and draw it 5 more times?

Answer (score 0):

You have to draw your bar-code multiple times in bitmap

```
int NoOfTimesToPrint = 5;

private void Doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(codigo_pic.Width, codigo_pic.Height);
    for(int i=1;i<=NoOfTimesToPrint;i++)
    {
        codigo_pic.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(5, i*5, codigo_pic.Width, codigo_pic.Height));    
    }
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0);
    bm.Dispose();
}
```

**Please Note you have to Change NoOfTimesToPrint variable in order to work this code as you need**

Answer (score 0):

```
int NumOfLabel = Convert.ToInt16(textBox_StockAddQuntity_StockEntry.Text); /* here for example i set to total copy */

PrintDialog pDlg = new PrintDialog();
pDlg.Document = printDocument_Barcode;
pDlg.AllowSelection = true;
pDlg.AllowSomePages = true;
pDlg.PrinterSettings.Copies = (short)NumOfLabel;
printDocument_Barcode.Print();
```